# sudoers with other user and colon ":" char

Tags: sudo

I require a sudoers to be able to execute following command

```
sudo -u myAppUser /opt/myapp/bin/myapp.Console.pl Admin::User::Add <some optional parameters>
```

I've created a group `myAppExecGroup` and added `myTestUser` to the group

```
Cmnd_Alias              MYAPPADDCMD = /opt/myapp/bin/myapp.Console.pl Admin\:\:User\:\:Add *

%myAppExecGroup ALL= (myAppUser) NOPASSWD: MYAPPADDCMD
```

as a counter test I tried this simple reboot, which works well

```
Cmnd_Alias              POWER = /sbin/shutdown, /sbin/halt, /sbin/reboot, /sbin/restart
%myAppExecGroup ALL= (root) NOPASSWD: POWER
```

also tried this, which is not working at all and asks for password

```
Cmnd_Alias              IFCONFIG = /sbin/fdisk --list
%myAppExecGroup ALL= (root) NOPASSWD: IFCONFIG
```

So I am not clear if I have a general lack of understanding or if I am facing a usage issue, which is hindering my requirement?

**update 1:**

this script can simulate the above named command

```
mkdir -p /opt/myapp/bin/
echo > /opt/myapp/bin/myapp.Console.pl
chmod 755 /opt/myapp/bin/myapp.Console.pl
tee -a /opt/myapp/bin/myapp.Console.pl <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
echo \$@
echo \$USER
EOF
```

**update 2:**

if using root instead of myAppUser

```
%myAppExecGroup ALL= (root) NOPASSWD: MYAPPADDCMD
```

the command executes. But I require myAppUser environment?!?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/356421/how-to-include-a-colon-in-specific-command-sudoers-entry#356424

Comment: I found the link before I posted my question. I am not clear what you want to refer here too? Escaping is done?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem with fdisk is with the path, try `which fdisk` to check the right path (I have it under /usr/sbin/fdisk)

The problem with your command is the space before the *, by writing `...User\:\:Add *` you imply optional parameters are mandatory, if you remove the space:

```
Cmnd_Alias              MYAPPADDCMD = /opt/myapp/bin/myapp.Console.pl Admin\:\:User\:\:Add*
```

it should accept your command with and without parameters

Comment: same behaviour, requests for password

Comment: i have updated my question, to give an option to simulate the command.

Comment: thanks, I did created a similar one already to test my answer before post it.
the only other reason I can think of is: is the user trying to sudo in the myAppExecGroup group?
(did you tried to check fdisk actual path?)

Comment: sure I require it in a group. Is your command working too if you add the user into a group and allow the group? Can you share your test too?

Comment: it did work with group as well, my sudo config are just like yours but with Cmnd_Alias without space as I did quote it in the answer.
One important question: you call the script with the full path or do you have /opt/myapp/bin in your path and then use myapp.Console.pl? If you do, can you paste the result of ```which myapp.Console.pl``` from both the user using sudo and myAppUser?

Comment: can you please share full configuration incl. script? not working at my end.